# Azure Logic App "When a work item is updated" trigger (Azure DevOps)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to create an Azure logic app "when a work item is updated'. In the design, I'm not able to get the previous value of the properties and I'm not able to set a specific property depends on a condition.

As example cases:
1. I want to react when a work item changes its state depends on the previous state.
2. I want to see if the user adds completed work into the work item.

Comment: How will you applying your azure logic app with azure devops? For me, I use **web hook ** to connect with my azure logic app. In web hook, I can choose only work item **state change** can trigger my azure logic app. In this trigger, it will send one JSON request body to logic app which contains previous state value and etc.

Comment: How you are triggering your application on state change?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT

Comment: Soory for late. In azure devops web hook, there has one trigger condition: **work item field changed**. Here I let the filed as **work item state**. Then I combine my azure logic app with that web hook. Now, once the work item state changed, the system will send a JSON body to my azure logic app. In this JSON body, it contains original state value , the new value and etc. I just need parse these JSON to get anything I want.